# Attempt to read from field 'androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to hide and show a fragment onResume method based on a condition but when the fragment loads, it shows a nullpointerexception :/

the xml of activity:

```
...
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentSettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.project.PinFragment" />
...
```

fragment part in activity:

```
private ... fragmentManager;
private ... pinFragment;
private ... fragmentTransaction; (initialized in class)
...
//in onResume method
                    if (condition) {
                        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        pinFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentSettings);
                        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.show(pinFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    } else {
                        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        pinFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentSettings);
                        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(pinFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    }
...
```

There is just a textview in the fragment file for testing purpose. Can someone show me where I did wrong? Thank you in advance.

Error shown on the line when the fragment is being loaded:
[image]

Comment: show error log.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya added logcat, it shows the error on the line when the fragment is called in the onresume method